# Python function slows down with presence of large list

Tags: python, performance, memory, allocation

I was testing the speeds of a few different ways to do complex iterations over some of my data, and I found something weird. It seems that having a large list local to some function slows down that function considerably, even if it is not touching that list. For example, creating 2 independent lists via 2 instances of the same generator function is about 2.5x slower the second time. If the first list is removed prior to creating the second, both iterators go at the same spee.

```
def f():  
    l1, l2 = [], []  
    for c1, c2 in generatorFxn():  
        l1.append((c1, c2))  
    # destroying l1 here fixes the problem 
    for c3, c4 in generatorFxn():  
        l2.append((c3, c4))
```

The lists end up about 3.1 million items long each, but I saw the same effect with smaller lists too. The first `for` loop takes about 4.5 seconds to run, the second takes 10.5. If I insert `l1= []` or `l1= len(l1)` at the comment position, both `for` loops take 4.5 seconds.

Why does the speed of local memory allocation in a function have anything to do with the current size of that function's variables?

EDIT:
Disabling the garbage collector fixes everything, so must be due to it running constantly. Case closed!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create that many new objects (3 million tuples), the garbage collector gets bogged down. If you turn off garbage collection with gc.disable(), the issue goes away (and the program runs 4x faster to boot).

Comment: Right you are sir, disabling it drops 4.5 sec to 1.3 sec, and almost eliminates the differences (the second one is still slightly slower, but not by much anymore). Why does the garbage collector run so slow even after a large list is made and is just existing, not being modified? Shouldn't it only have work to do once the function returns?

Comment: Also, why does the slow-down go away if `l` is a class variable instead of a local variable?

Comment: Here's my best guess: the garbage collector runs periodically to collect old objects. It determines when to run by looking comparing the number of allocated and deallocated objects since the last collection. If allocated-deallocated > threshold, the collector runs (and threshold=700 by default). Since you create (at least) 1 new object per iteration, the collector is running 3e6/700 = 4285 times. This actually slows down both iterations, but the second iteration is slower since there are more objects for the collector to check.

Comment: I'll add two easy suggestions for avoiding this issue:  1) start with 2 lists and append values onto those rather than creating 3 million tuples.  2) Increase the garbage collection threshold (at least temporarily) during the list generation

Comment: Thanks, both suggestions make a lot of sense and I'll remember to use them. Also, upon retesting today, setting `l` as a class variable no longer seems to fix the problem. I must have been testing something wrong yesterday. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to say without more detailed instrumentation.

As a very, very preliminary step, check your main memory usage. If your RAM is all filled up and your OS is paging to disk, your performance will be quite dreadful. In such a case, you may be best off taking your intermediate products and putting them somewhere other than in memory. If you only need sequential reads of your data, consider writing to a plain file; if your data follows a strict structure, consider persisting into a relational database.

Comment: Each item in the lists is a tuple of 2 strings, each 3 characters long. And I've seen the same effect with smaller lists; at a list size of 770,000 each, the times are 0.57 and 0.96 seconds. At 188,000 they are 0.11 and 0.15 seconds. I'm quite sure it isn't a memory threshold that I'm crossing, as I'm on a 64-bit system with 4gb of ram.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that when the first list is made, there is more memory available, meaning less chance that the list needs to be reallocated as it grows.

After you take up a decent chunk of memory with the first list, your second list has a higher
chance of needing to be reallocated as it grows since python lists are dynamically sized.

Comment: + 1 for making a lot of sense and reminding me memory allocation (usually) isn't in 1 big chunk. According to Activity Monitor, both lists together required about 280mb of space, so that is a fair chunk.

Answer (score 0):

The memory used by the data local to the function isn't going to be garbage-collected until the function returns.  Unless you have a need to do slicing, using lists for large collections of data is not a great idea.

From your example it's not entirely clear what the purpose of creating these lists are.  You might want to consider using generators instead of lists, especially if the lists are just going to be iterated.  If you need to do slicing on the return data, cast the generators to lists at that time.

Comment: Creating these lists was initially done simply to test the speed of different generator functions, but I will have to create lists like these once I find an appropriate algorithm. The question isn't about finding a better way to store the data, but rather why there is such a drastic performance hit. It makes no sense to me, and I'd like to keep the answer in mind when programming in the future.

And I know the garbage collection won't be happening in the middle of the function, which is why re-assigning `l` shouldn't fix the problem (and yet it does).