# Python Subprocess.pOpen runs slow when memory is occ

Tags: python, subprocess

I wrote a python script that uses `subprocess.Popen` to call command line tool `look` to do the binary search on a file.

#### For example

```
p = subprocess.Popen('look -b "abc" testfile.txt',executable='/bin/bash', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
result = out.decode()
print(result)
```

What this snippet of code does is that it calls the system command look to perform a binary search the file called `testfile.txt` for the string `abc`.

It works fine if you just have this snippet of code.

However, when your memory is loaded with some large files, it becomes significantly slow.

For example, if you do:

```
a = read_a_large_file() #Like GBs of data
p = subprocess.Popen('look -b "abc" testfile.txt',executable='/bin/bash', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
result = out.decode()
print(result)
a[0]
```

The subprocess part takes a very long time to execute. Running the look command is very fast in shell as it performs binary search on sorted files.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running it directly from your shell when you are short of memory? If that is also slow, it is the `look` command, that becomes slow, and it has nothing to do with Python `subprocess`.

Comment: Yes, running the look command directly is very fast in shell as it is binary search on a sorted file

Comment: Even when memory consumption is high?

Comment: Have same problem. Only loading large file change `%time subprocess.Popen(['echo', '"blah"'])` from 3ms to 580ms

Comment: @Thran seems like the only solution is avoiding using subprocess with memory intensive tasks.

Comment: I have also observed this same issue. My workaround is to do all data processing work in one script and make the subprocess call(s) in a separate script which requires as little data as possible to execute (and then write any relevant data to disk). This results in a 2x speedup in my case.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. My workaround is to  minimize the memory usage as much as possible when I need subprocess calls. Another option is to run a separate process that does subprocess call and communicate with the main process with socket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function slows down with presence of large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823465/python-function-slows-down-with-presence-of-large-list)

Comment: On further investigation, the slowest line is `part = os.read(errpipe_read, 50000)` in subprocess; but even if the garbage collector is disabled, it's still a little slower.

Comment: I've encounter the same problem. The root cause for me is when the parent process memory is large, the `clone` and `execve` syscall is much slower. If you could trigger `os.posix_spawn` in Python3.8, it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Before reading a large file, `subprocess.popen()` executes a command which takes about 20ms, however, after reading a large file, the same command takes 300ms. It's 10 times slower! After a long time debugging this, I found out that the parameter `close_fds` greatly influences the performance!

`close_fds` is a parameter that will be set to `True` by default. However, after setting it to `False`c `subprocess.popen(cmd, close_fds=False)` makes the command performs normally.